# qTip: show tooltip when element becomes visible

Tags: jquery, show, hidden, qtip

I have a qTip tooltip attached to an element on my page whose parent `<div>` is hidden (`display: none`). I want to show the tooltip automatically when the parent becomes visible (`display: block`). Is this possible?

Sample HTML:

```
<div id="parent" style="display: none;">
    <div id="child">Child Element</div>
</div>
```

JS:

```
$("#child").qtip();
```

I've tried using the `ready` option to trigger the tooltip automatically:

```
$("#child").qtip({
    ready: true
});
```

But this makes the tooltip appear immediately even though the parent `<div>` is hidden.

qTip also provides a `when` option, in which you can display the tooltip when a certain event occurs, but this only accepts built-in jQuery events. I can't find a way to define my own function and show the tooltip when the `display` value of the parent `<div>` is `block`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a custom event,

```
$("#child").qtip({
    show: { when: { target: $("#child").parent(), event: "showevent" } }
});

$("#parent").show().trigger("showevent");
```

http://craigsworks.com/projects/qtip/docs/reference/

Comment: I used a variation of this to show different qtips for valid and invalid input.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you might have to simply trigger `qtip()` in the same place you trigger to show the parent (however you do that).

```
$('#whatever').on('click', function () { // just as an example
    $('#parent').show();
    $('#child').qtip();
});
```